# How to find if Windows Service is started manually or by OS?

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

I have a Windows service which is started manually.

There is also a restart time in service which makes it to restart itself. For this I exit by giving a `>0` number to OS and in the Service -> recovery tab, I have set service to restart on first, second and subsequent failures.

```
Environment.Exit(1)
```

But how to find out if service is started manually or by OS?

Comment: Odd question.  If the service is always started manually then of course you **know** it was not started automatically.  The recovery keys have no effect at all.

Comment: The last comment (from Hans Passant) is correct. Unfortunately, the initial  is NOT answered in this Posting.  My service is set to "Autostart" and I REALLY need to now, if the start was automatically (after a reboot) or manually (started by user). Somebody has a solution for this (else, I would have to post exactly the same question, what I don't want to do)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take it from `registry`:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\YourServiceName
```

Registry Key: `Start` (REG_DWORD)

Values:
1 -> System
2 -> Automatic
3 -> Manual
4 -> Disabled

You can also do

```
new ServiceController("YourServiceName")
```

and then do some **P/Invoke** fun: http://peterkellyonline.blogspot.de/2011/04/configuring-windows-service.html

Comment: Does this registry value change?

Comment: I think it reflects how the service is set up, that is startup type

Comment: This does not answer the initial question that really does not make sense regarding the "problem". My service is set to "Autostart", but I really need to now, if the start was automatically (after a reboot) or manually (started by user). Do you have a solution for this (else, I would have to post exactly the same question, what I don't want to do)??